# Can search engine find ReactJS component when using with Laravel

Tags: seo, javascript, laravel

I am new to `ReactJS` and `Laravel` and trying to build a web app using these both technologies.

https://medium.com/@adelekandavid2013/reactjs-app-with-laravel-restful-api-endpoint-part-1-b3991dbf99f2

I am following the article *link given above* to integrate `ReactJS` component in `Lavarel` for `View`.

Can search engine like *google* would be able to find view create using `ReactJS Components` instead of blade templates, or I have to use blade instead (*my first priority is to use ReactJS for the VIEW instead of Blade templates*).

Comment: I don't use React.js, so I don't know for sure.   We are getting lots of questions from folks about problems with Google crawling their single page applications, especially those built with Angular.  The way to test it is to put up a few test pages on your site, log into Google Search Console, and use the "Fetch as Google" feature.  When you "fetch and render" that will show you exactly what Googlebot is able to see.

Comment: That might be best one choice to test my app. Thank you @StephenOstermiller